# How to play a youtube video in popup?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, youtube

I am trying a create a popup window which will play the youtube video. But I don't know, for some reason it is not happening. I have included the code below of what I have tried. I am trying to use it in wordpress.

```
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/2cxqZiWyW3g&hl=en_US&fs=1&autoplay=1"
class="video-link">Video 1</a>
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/607RMNoJfl4&hl=en_US&fs=1&autoplay=1"
class="video-link">Video 2</a>

 <div class="modal" id="video-modal">
  <div id="video-container" style="width: 425px; height: 344px;"></div>
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
    var videoModal = $('#video-modal').overlay({
        expose: {
            color: 'black',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.85
        },
        closeOnClick: true,
        api: true
    });

    $('.video-link').click(function() {
        videoModal.load();

        var videoUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {
            allowFullScreen: "true",
            allowscriptaccess: "always"
        };
        var attributes = {};

        swfobject.embedSWF(videoUrl, 'video-container', '425', '344', '9.0.0', '', flashvars, params, attributes);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Can someone correct me where I am going wrong. On clicking the link it is taking to the youtube video.

Comment: Any error message in the console?

Answer (score 2):

To add video in popup you can also use

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/(ID of video)?parameters
```

in your case

```
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2cxqZiWyW3g?autoplay=1"
class="video-link">Video 1</a>
```

I have created codepen for it , please check it
http://codepen.io/unmeshdusane/pen/WQKvPQ

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to your click

```
$('.video-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
...
});
```

Comment: `return false;` should achieve the same - it is equivalent to `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score -1):

you can use This

your Links

```
<a href="#play" onclick="popupYT('2cxqZiWyW3g')">Video 1</a>

<a href="#play" onclick="popupYT('607RMNoJfl4')">Video 2</a>
```

and the Script

```
    <script>
    function popupYT(id) {
    window.open('https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+id, 'popup', config='height=375,width=450')
    }
   </script>
```

Very Simple and works

Comment: It is not a popup. It is a new widow

Comment: Yes it is a new popup Window for the most Browser. With popup blocker. You can use this with jquery ui or wahtever.

Its Simple and works ;-)